# Open MP without respawn team of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, atomic

I have the following code structure and would like to parallelize the loop in `function2` using OpenMP:

```
// main.cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
 function1();
}

// function1 in module1.cpp
float sum = 0;
std::vector<float> numbers = /* a vector of 20000 random floats */
for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
 function2(sum, numbers);
}

// function2 in module2.cpp
for (int z = 0; z < numbers.size(); ++z) {
 atomicSum(sum, numbers[z]);
}
```

I attempted to use `#pragma omp parallel for` to parallelize the loop in `function2`, but it creates a new team of threads for each iteration of `j` in `function1`, resulting in unnecessary overhead.

My goal is to create a single team of threads at the beginning of the main module and reuse this team for the parallelization of the loop in `function2`. How can I achieve this using OpenMP efficiently?

Additionally, of course, it is important to note that the line `atomicSum(sum, numbers[z]);` must be atomic, because the variable 'sum' will be shared by every thread.

Comment: An implementation is allowed to reuse threads, and real-world implementations do this. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/shW9965M3. Each call of `function1` will thus very likely reuse the threads created in its firts call. Anyway, you can also _collapse_ nested loops, but they would likely need to be in the same block (I am not sure about this).

Comment: 1. How do you observe that thrads are being re-created? 2. I've tested and found very little overhead since thread pools are typically re-used. 3. Since you're writing C++ you should really use range-based syntax: `for ( auto z : numbers)`. It works and is much nicer to look at.

Comment: Additionally, you should not expect any speed-up by parallelizing a loop that is made only of atomic operations.

Comment: What OpenMP implementation are you using on what OS?  Also, it would only take a little bit more code to make this a [mcve] that people could copy/paste and try, e.g.  by including the line that defines the function arg types to I assume take `float &sum` by reference?

Comment: "atomic, because the variable 'sum' will be shared by every thread." You should use `reduction`.